# On Google Or-Tools, how can we set time window on Vehicles?

Tags: or-tools

I'm touching Google Or-tools to solve VRPtw problem and struggling with setting the time window on the vehicles.
It is clear to add time window on the locations but I didn't find the way of setting those on the vehicles side. On the practical situation, it is that each vehicle's driver has fixed break time and on that term, they don't move or visit somewhere. They are deactivated.

Thank you for reading the questions and your help.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "time windows" associated to vehicle.

1. You can set a TW on the cumulVar of the vehicle's end node
2. For break, you should take a look on the examples we provided
   e.g. https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/cpp/cvrptw_with_breaks.cc

Comment: Thank you!
With this reply and example, I got it!